# I get a NullReferenceException when I use FindControl to find controls in either master or content pages

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, themes

I am trying to create reversible themes in ASP.NET. I can successfully change themes using a dropdown list, but I am running into problems changing SkinID's and generic HTML controls (which are all div's except for the body tag) programmatically. I moved all my attribute- and skin-changing code to the PreInit method of my Base Page. Now I get a NullReferenceException when I run the page. I thought this code was supposed to use the existing controls it is supposedly pointing to. What am I missing or doing wrong?

Here is my code:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: On which line you are getting this error?

Comment: The first one - "Dim bodyControl As HtmlGenericControl...". I included part of the PreInit method so you could see what I am trying to do.

Comment: Do you have `runat=server ` and `id` attributes on your body control something like this `<body runat="server" id="mybody">` ?

Comment: Yes. All important divs have `code`runat="server"`code`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `PreInit` event is probably too early in the page lifecycle to look for controls with `FindControl`.  You're also doing your declarations outside of the event.  That may have something to do with your null reference as well.  I'd see if you can change it to look later in the lifecycle.  This may be helpful if you haven't already seen it:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Comment: It worked as soon as I moved the controls from the top of the page and into the `code`PreInit() method! Thanks SO much!